# Is it possible to upgrade the version of less compiler in sails.js

Tags: less, sails.js

Hi Im using sails in my application (version 0.9.16).

How do I know the version of the less compiler in sails.js? I've tried to look it in a package inside the node_modules, but none of them could indicated the less compiler version. Is it also possible to upgrade the less-compiler (not the whole sails.js)?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

Sails 0.9. uses **grunt-contrib-less 0.9.0** (you found this in your packages.json in your sails app).

You can try:

- Upgrade sails to 0.10 (beta) - here is **0.11.1** included. Use **npm install sails@beta**. The 0.10-version is not far away from being released und have many good improvements.
- Update your grunt-contrib-less in your Sails-App with **npm install grunt-contrib-less --save** in your project-dir.

Comment: 0.10 has been released since August. You no longer need to use *sails@beta* just sails.